# Converting a sequence chart to Python code

Tags: python, structure

[image: Sequence Diagram for adding two numbers and calculating the average]

```
def Input_Numbers():
    global Number1
    global Number2
    Number1 = int(input("please enter a value for Number 1 : "))
    Number2 = int(input("please enter a value for Number 2 : "))

def Calculate_average(Number1,Number2):
    Average = (Number1 + Number2)/2
    return Average

def Output_average(Average):
    print(Average)
    return Average


Input_Numbers()
Calculate_average(Number1,Number2)
Output_average(Average)
```

Here is my attempt of representing the structure chart but I'm not sure if it is correct

Comment: Can you please fix the code indentation

Comment: Mandatory: Fix the indentation. Strong suggestions: Get rid of `global` and respect the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: You return the average from `Calculate_average` but you don't use the value. You want `average = calculate_average(number1, number2)` (capitalization of names adjusted to Python standard).

Comment: No, this is not an assignment but we are learning how structure charts are used to show sub tasks of a program. To help my understanding as a student I'm inclined to represent this chart as a working program in Python as I have started learning Python in school. I want to represent how the arrows are demonstrating that the parameters are going into the different sub modules

Comment: @HamzahKhan Check out the below solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it should be as follows:

```
def input_Numbers():
    number1 = int(input("Please enter a value for Number 1 : "))
    number2 = int(input("Please enter a value for Number 2 : "))
    return number1,number2

def calculate_Average(number1,number2):
    average = (number1 + number2)/2
    return average

def output_Average(average):
    print(average)

number1, number2 = input_Numbers()
average = calculate_Average(number1,number2)
output_Average(average)
```